# Trying to override the base handler on a SO Line checkbox field

Tags: acumatica

I'd like to override the "Free Item" logic on the Sales Order form. I've got a function that is calculating the final price based on a number of criteria, as such I'd like to avoid having it wipe out the Unit Price field.

I've created the following code:

```cs
protected void SOLine_IsFree_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null) InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

  SOLine row = e.Row as SOLine;
  // My Price calculation formula goes here.
}
```

This works, but of course the following line runs the default code:

```cs
if(InvokeBaseHandler != null) InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
```

But if I eliminate it, I can check the checkbox (and it works) but I can't ever un-check it. Attempting to un-check it seems to do nothing. I tried setting the value of that in the code, thinking maybe that was the problem. Also tried duplicating the code it was running by default and nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "I can't ever un-check it" you mean the IsFree field is disabled in UI? If so, you may want to check the SetEnable for that field on RowSelected handler and see if you would need to change its bevavior. (i.e. PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLine.isFree>(sender, e.Row, !autoFreeItem && row.InventoryID != null); )

Comment: Nailed it. Added an event handler for Row selected and enabled it and I'm perfect (which nicely coincides with the next step in my process, which was making some fields editable only in certain cases.)

Comment: Great! I have added comment as answer below too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IsFree field is disabled in UI then, you want to check the SetEnable<> for that field on RowSelected handler and see if you would need to change its bevavior.

See sample below:

```
protected virtual void SOLine_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e, PXRowSelected baseMethod)
{
   //Calling Base method
   if(basemethod != null)
        basemethod(sender, e);
   ................................................
   PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOLine.isFree>(sender, e.Row, !autoFreeItem && row.InventoryID != null);                                                    
}
```